# Change default encoding for RubyMine?

Tags: encoding, rubymine

Is it possible to change the default encoding for RubyMine to be UTF-8 instead of MacRoman or ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MacOSX open RubyMine->Preferences, in Windows and Linux probably settings somewhere. Then go to General and IDE Encoding. Pick UTF-8 there.

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings (or Ctrl + Atl + S)

Click the "General" selection under IDE Settings and select from the "IDE Encoding:"  drop down menu at the bottom.